# Computing the class number using the prime factorization of the discriminant

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, nt.number-theory

i was wondering if there is a way to use the prime factorization of the discriminant $d$ when computing the class number $h(d)$. E.g., assume you have an integer $n = pq$ with $p \equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $q \equiv 3\pmod{4}$, with known primes $p$ and $q$ and the imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-n})$. Then $d  = -n = -pq$ and you want to compute $h(d)$. Do there exists an algorithm the uses the knowledge of $p$ and $q$ or the class numbers $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-q})$ to compute the class number $h(d)$?

There is an answer to a complexity question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146272/how-long-does-it-take-to-compute-a-class-number) from 2013, which at least indicates that the best known algorithm ($\mathcal{O}(D^{1/4+\epsilon})$ with GRH or $\mathcal{O}(D^{1/2+\epsilon})$ without GRH) does not utilize this.

Regards,
Etsch